# Element-wise powering vs. discrete version of binomial theorem on a sum of Gaussians

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, superresolution

I had recently posted a question on applying powers on a sum of Gaussians ([here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60721/applying-a-power-on-a-sum-of-gaussians-to-enhance-resolution/60737#60737)) to enhance signal resolution artificially. The discussion has given rise to another query. Consider this problem. We have two Gaussian time functions $G_1$ and $G_2$. Suppose we wish sum these Gaussians and raise it to a power of 2.

**Situation no. 1**: $(G_1+G_2)^2$, we should get another function $G$= $G_1^2$ + $2G_1G_2$ + $G_2^2$. The product of two $G_1G_2$ is another Gaussian. We should see three peaks in this case.

**Situation no. 2**: We sum the two Gaussians element wise i.e., $S_i$ = $g(t)_{1i}$ + $g(t)_{2i}$ where $g(t)_i$ 's are the corresponding elements of $G_1$ + $G_2$. Now each summed element $S_i$ is raised to power 2. We get only two peaks as a result.

I discussed this issue with some of my colleagues including the person who had proposed this method; they seek agree that both operations are equivalent. It seems they are not, because in situation 2, we will never see $G_1G_2$. What would the discrete version of situation 1?

I feel there is some fallacy here and some mathematical insight should be able to settle this problem.

Thanks.

For Situation no. 2: Here is the MATLAB code.

```
t=[0:1/200:60]';

u1= 19; % mu the mean time peak i

u2= 22; % mu the mean time peak j

A= 250; %Area

s_ij=[0.84 0.87];; %s_ij represent the sigma of i,j pair; Choose elements by indexing

G_ij=A*normpdf(t, u1, s_ij(1,1))+ A*normpdf(t, u2, s_ij(1,2)); %Sum normpdf is a built in function for a unit area Gaussian from statistical package.

Power= (G_ij).^2;

subplot(2,1,1); plot(t,G_ij);title('Unresolved Gaussians');

subplot(2,1,2); plot (t, Power);title ('Gaussian Sum Raised to Power 2');
```

Comment: i might make a stab at answering this question, but i still don't see this question described adequately.  there is more to a random signal in the time domain than it's p.d.f. (which is gaussian). there are also the spectral characteristics which are often described with a power spectral density or with the autocorrelation of a stochastic signal. anyway, to be consistent with electrical engineering convention, you should denote the time functions as "$g_1(t)$" and "$g_2(t)$". and define how they are related to each other (if they are at all), but we need the p.d.f. and autocorrelation at least

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I am afraid this is not as complicated. I am a chemist, and the sum of two simple Gaussians are just a simulation of two chromatogram peaks. There is no correlation concept involved here, as far I can understand and the position of two peaks is not all related -just two arbitrary peaks.

Comment: I don't see a definition for `G_ij` in the code.

Comment: Corrected. G_ij

Comment: In the first plot you have the sum of two Gaussians. In the second, you have the sum squared. I don't understand why you think the two should be the same?

Comment: @M.Farooq Please see the additions I made to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
([a b c] .+ [d e f]).^2 = [a+d b+e c+f].^2
                        = [(a+d)^2 (b+e)^2 (c+f)^2]
                        = [a^2+2ad+d^2 b^2+2be+e^2 c^2+2cf+f^2]
```

I suspect that:

- The problem may be in your assumptions: "We should see three peaks in this case" sounds like a hypothesis that may be false.
- You may have a bug in your code, which might be why "We get only two peaks as a result".

Here is some code to illustrate that `(A.+B).^2 = A.^2 .+ 2A.*B .+ B.^2`:

```
t=0:1/200:60;
gauss1 = 250*normpdf(t,19,0.84);
gauss2 = 250*normpdf(t,22,0.87);
m1 = gauss1.^2+2*gauss1.*gauss2+gauss2.^2;
m2 = (gauss1+gauss2).^2;
fprintf('Difference: %1.2f\n', sum(abs(m1-m2)));
subplot(2,1,1);plot(m1);title('Method 1');
subplot(2,1,2);plot(m2);title('Method 2');
```

I get:

```
Difference: 0.00
```

and

[image]

So, the math is correct. You may still be wondering, how come the third Gaussian $G_1G_2$ is not apparent in the plot? This is the point where it's useful to challenge your assumption that the third Gaussian should be visible. If we plot $G_1G_2$ by itself we obtain:

```
plot(2*gauss1.*gauss2);
```

[image]

Look at the amplitude and the position in the x-axis: this third Gaussian is not apparent in the plot because it is completely swamped by the other two, much larger, surrounding peaks.

Comment: I am afraid there is no fancy code, I am just doing it in Excel or Matlab. I think there is some other fundamental fallacy.

Comment: I doubt it. The problem is not complex enough to hide a fallacy. If you share your code I'll take a look at it.

Comment: added the code for the sake of completeness. Thanks.

Comment: I was just about to post an answer when I saw that @MBaz nailed it. I got the same thing, as expected. I already upvoted this answer.  So I will e-mail what I have separately to M. Farooq.

Comment: So we do generate a new peak when we square element-wise. Thanks for double checking and confirming this problem.

Comment: @M.Farooq You're welcome -- glad to be of help.